# Navigation back button on Android is not working

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have wrote this code to enable the navigation back button. Its appearing on run time but after clicking on it is not doing anything. Can someone tell me please what I'm missing?

```java
// Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

// Enable the Up button
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you don't use the [tag:android-studio] tag for questions not relating to Android Studio, it makes it difficult for people to find your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `onOptionsItemSelected` method in your activity.

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            finish()
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Also if i'm not mistaken you should add this to your action bar to:

```
supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
```